# Get email addresses of followers of a Github repo

Tags: node.js, github, npm

I am looking to send out a one time email to the followers of a Github repo to announce the first release.

This is answer is pretty good:
https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-send-a-message-or-email-to-all-the-followers-of-GitHub-Repo/answer/PoAn-Baron-Chen-1?srid=Xt2o

The Github API has a way to get the followers of a user - 
https://developer.github.com/v3/users/followers/#list-followers-of-a-user

...but ... is there a way to get a list of the followers of a Github repo?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [github-email-explorer](https://github.com/yuecen/github-email-explorer) looks like it does what you're trying to do.

First line from the README:

> For people who want to create an email marketing plan for particular group on GitHub, github-email-explorer can collect addresses from a repository you want, and then send email content to those email addresses.

Comment: I guess I would prefer an NPM module to do this, but maybe I could use this thanks!